# Multi Client TCP Server not acceping some clients c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I am trying to make a server that will accept clients, and will communicate with them until they say "exit".
the problem is, after 5-8 clients, the server decides that he don't want to accept any more clients, and when a client is connected.. I simply don't see a "client connected : 123.242.123.13:92313" in the console.
anyone knows the problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace GatherServer
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int connections = 0, team1 = 0, team2 = 0, playing = 12;
        public static string lbleader = "";
        public static bool isleader = false;
        static TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 7846);
        static void Listeners()
        {
            string charname = "";
            bool inque = false;
            Socket socketForClient = myList.AcceptSocket();
            if(socketForClient.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client Connected: " + socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint);
                NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(socketForClient);
                StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(networkStream);
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(networkStream);

                while (true)
                {
                    string newString = streamReader.ReadLine();
                    if (newString.Contains("#") && inque == false)
                    {
                        if (newString.Contains("Leader"))
                        {
                            newString = newString.Replace("Leader","");
                            if (!isleader)
                            {
                                isleader = true;
                                lbleader = newString;
                                charname = lbleader;
                                Console.WriteLine(lbleader + " is the gather leader");
                            }
                        }
                        inque = true;
                        charname = newString;
                        connections++;
                        Console.WriteLine("connections: " + connections + " | from: "+charname);

                    }
                    if (newString == "exit")
                    {
                        if (charname == lbleader)
                        {
                            isleader = false;
                            Console.WriteLine(lbleader + " Left, there is not active leader");
                        }
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine(charname + " has left the game: "+socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint);
                        if (inque == true)
                            connections--;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        streamWriter.WriteLine(connections.ToString());
                        streamWriter.Flush();
                        if (connections == 12)
                        {
                            if (!isleader)
                            {
                                lbleader = charname;
                                Console.WriteLine(lbleader + " is the gather leader");
                                isleader = true;
                            }
                            Random rnd = new Random();
                            int team = rnd.Next(1, 3); // creates a number between 1 and 2
                            if(team == 1)
                            {
                                if (team1 < 6)
                                {
                                    team1++;
                                    Console.WriteLine(newString + " " + socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint + " assigned to Team 1");
                                    streamWriter.WriteLine("team1"+lbleader);
                                    streamWriter.Flush();
                                    inque = false;
                                    playing--;
                                    break;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(newString + " " + socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint + " assigned to Team 2");
                                    team2++;
                                    streamWriter.WriteLine("team2" + lbleader);
                                    streamWriter.Flush();
                                    inque = false;
                                    playing--;
                                    break;
                                }

                            }
                            if(team == 2)
                            {
                                if (team2 < 6)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(newString + " " + socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint + " assigned to Team 2");
                                    team2++;
                                    streamWriter.WriteLine("team2" + lbleader);
                                    streamWriter.Flush();
                                    inque = false;
                                    playing--;
                                    break;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(newString + " " + socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint + " assigned to Team 1");
                                    team1++;
                                    streamWriter.WriteLine("team1" + lbleader);
                                    streamWriter.Flush();
                                    inque = false;
                                    playing--;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }  
                    }
                }
                if (playing == 0)
                {
                    connections = playing;
                    playing = 12;
                    lbleader = null;
                    isleader = false;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("playing:" + playing);
                Console.WriteLine("connections: " + connections);
                inque = false;
                streamWriter.Close();
                streamReader.Close();
                networkStream.Close();
                socketForClient.Close();
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            myList.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Sever is up and running...");

            for(int i=0; i<1000;i++)
            {
                Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listeners));
                newThread.Start();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Basically, what I want to do is to give each client a thread of its own. but after 5-8 connections, the server Socket socketForClient = myList.AcceptSocket(); not working, I think its because I am running out of threads.. but I have no clue why, there should be 1000 threads open when only 5 to 8 connections are made.

please help!

Comment: A thousand threads for your application is a `horrible` idea! You are wasting the resources as all the threads are trying to run. You should use much less number of threads, and, even better, use the `ThreadPool` instead of direct thread creation.

Comment: did this.. still not working

Comment: Can you post a new code for this?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/j2U8pGzW

Answer (score 0):

Found out what was the problem, I was highlighting some stuff in the server console, which caused the server to pause.